# Increase the number of links new users can post in answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, rate-limiting

I asked a question about a particular project, and luckily was able to get in touch with the author of the software. On Stack Overflow, he provided an answer to my question. In this answer, he wanted to provide links to references, but complained that he could only leave 1 link in his answer since he was a new user.

I can understand why this was put in place, but can the limit be raised to something like 3 or 5? With all the self-policing that goes I think spammers would likely be caught very quickly. Raising the limit would aid in furnishing the completeness of an answer.

Comment: Simple: the other person put answer with only one or two links. You upvote the answer. The other person now has 11 reputation and can post as many links as he desires so you put comment on his answer asking him to edit. (Hoping nobody will downvote :))

Answer (score 5):

You need 10 rep to post those links. All that should require is a single upvote and you should be good to go. If you make a little comment saying that you can't post the links because of your rep limit, someone will undoubtedly come and give you a sympathy vote to allow you (I've done this numerous times to people who have come into the IRC chan asking this same question).

Answer (score -3):

Well, what I did was post a second answer (temporarily!) to contain my second link. Then, when I got an upvote, I deleted the extra answer and put the link where I had wanted it in the first place. Not pretty, but it worked.

Comment: -1, I'm sure that kind of behavior is frowned upon and should not be encouraged